# Can a countable union of sets of measure zero have nonzero measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm fairly certain the answer is no, since if $E$ is a countable union of sets $E_k$, then countable subadditivity gives $m(E)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(E_k)$. But I can't figure out why this "counterexample" isn't actually a counterexample:

If we let $F_n$ be the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ with decimal expansion of length $n$, each $F_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ so they all have measure zero. But every $x\in[0,1]$ has a countably infinite decimal expansion (or at least has a representation $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k 10^{-k}$), so the (countable) union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$ is equal to a set of nonzero measure, namely $[0,1]$. Can anyone help me figure out where this reasoning breaks down?

Comment: The union of the sets $F_n$ is simply the set of rationals in $[0,1]$ with terminating decimal expansions. It isn’t even all of the rationals in the unit interval. (It does not, for instance, include $\frac13$ or $\frac17$, let alone $\pi-3$.) These are the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ that, when expressed as a fraction in lowest terms, have a denominator of the form $2^k5^\ell$ for some $k,\ell\ge 0$.

Comment: But as the lengths of the decimal expansions become infinitely long, don't the $F_n$ begin to approach $[0,1]$?

Comment: The limit points of sequences in a set are not necessarily in the set, unless the set is closed. The set is not closed.

Comment: @kieransquared If $\frac{1}{3} \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}  F_n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3} \in F_n$ for some $n$. But the latter is not true, so $\frac{1}{3}$ is not in fact in this union.

Comment: @kieransquared: $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$ is a dense subset of $[0,1]$, so every real number in $[0,1]$ is the limit of a sequence of numbers in $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$, but that does not mean that every real number in $[0,1]$ is actually in the set $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$. For a similar phenomenon, note that $0$ is the limit of the numbers $\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but $0$ is not one of those numbers: there is no positive integer whose reciprocal is $0$.

Comment: $0.333\ldots$ is NOT an element of the set
$$S=\{0.3,0.33,0.333,0.3333,\cdots\}.$$ All the elements of $S$ have finitely many decimals whereas $0.333\ldots$ has infinitely many.

Comment: It is true that every element of $[0,1]$ can be **approximated arbitrarily well by** elements of $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}F_i$. However, that's not at all the same thing as every element of $[0,1]$ **literally being** an element of $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}F_i$.

Answer (score 1):

All of the partial sums, or in other words all of the rationals in $[0,1]$ with terminating decimal expansions are in the union, but not necessarily their limit points. You are proceeding as though the union is closed, but it isn't. Keep in mind that this union would be a countable set with full measure, and by countable sub-additivity that is impossible since its measure is equal to 0 after re-indexing and comparing it to the countable sum of singletons.